# Why I obtain this fatal error "Class 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider' not found" trying to implement my custom user provider in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

I am absolutly new in **PHP** and **Laravel**, I came from Java.

I am trying to follow this tutorial to implement a **custom user provider**:

https://blog.georgebuckingham.com/laravel-52-auth-custom-user-providers-drivers/

I briefly expain what I need: my **Laravel** application is only a front end application, all the business logic, included the user authentication, is performed by a Java back end application that exposes REST web services.

Performing a call to:

```
http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login
```

and passing username and password as **basic authentication** I obtain a JSON response like this that represent the logged user:

```
{
  "userName": "Painkiller",
  "email": "painkiller@gmail.com",
  "enabled": true
}
```

So, in my Laravel application, I have to perform this call and then parse the previous returned JSON object to generate the authenticated object into the front end application session.

I think that the previous **custom user provider** is the neater and most natural solution to do it, but I am finding some difficulties and I have many doubts about how do it in my project.

I am using **Larave 5.3** version.

I have done the following steps (following the previous tutorial and trying to adapt it to my needs):

**1) Stage 1: Register your custom user provider:**

I have created my **service provider** in which I have register mycustom authentication user provider (the custom component used to perform my custom login via web service).

So into the **app** directory of my Laravel project I have created the **Authentication** subdirectory and here I have put this **AuthServiceProvider** that extends **ServiceProvider**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Authentication;

use Auth;
use App\Authentication\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Auth::provider('our_provider', function ($app, array $config) {
            return new UserProvider();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This simply registers your user provider/driver, making it usable in the config/auth.php file via the our_provider key.

**FIRST DOUBT**: passing the mouse on the:

```
use Auth;
```

it result **Undefined class Auth**, why? It seems to me that it is not used in the previous code, maybe a tutorial inclusion error or am I missing something?

Then I registerd this service into my **config/app.php** file:

This is the **providers** section of this file:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */

    //

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    App\Authentication\AuthServiceProvider::class,

],
```

as you can see this array contains my **App\Authentication\AuthServiceProvider::class,** representing the previous **ServiceProvider**. Is it correct?

**2: Stage 2: Update config to use new driver:**

I tell to my Laravel application to use the previous user provider, so I go into the **config/auth.php** configuration file and I set my provider:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'our_provider',
    ],
],
```

For the sake of completeness I post the entire content of my **config/auth.php** so you can see if there are some other error:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    /*
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'our_provider',
        ],


        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

3) **Stage 3: Create a user class:**

I think that this is something like a **model object** that will contains the data received from my web service (if the user can log into the system).

So if I am not missing something it have to contains a structure like this (username, email, ebabled fields):

```
{
  "userName": "Painkiller",
  "email": "painkiller@gmail.com",
  "enabled": true
}
```

According to the tutorial **this user class must implement the Laravel Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable interface**.

So into the **/app/Authentication** class (the same one that contains the previous **AuthServiceProvicer** class) I put this **User** class implementing the **Authenticatable** interface:

```
<?php

namespace App\Authentication;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class User implements Authenticatable {
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        // Return the name of unique identifier for the user (e.g. "id")
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        // Return the unique identifier for the user (e.g. their ID, 123)
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        // Returns the (hashed) password for the user
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        // Return the token used for the "remember me" functionality
    }

    /**
     * @param  string $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        // Store a new token user for the "remember me" functionality
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        // Return the name of the column / attribute used to store the "remember me" token
    }
}
```

**DOUBT:** The tutorial example put in this class only the stubbded methods, I have no token and I think that I only want to retrieve te previous user**name, email, ebabled fields**. So I think that this class is incomplete. Whate have I exactly to do? Create these 3 fields (that represent the user information returned by my web service) and the related getter methods? Is it or am I missing something?

**4) Stage 4: Create a UserProvider class:**

In stage 1, I have a **callback function** which returned an instance of **App\Authentication\UserProvider**, this class is used to **retrieve instances of our users App\Authentication\User**.

This class have to implement the **Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider** interface. It seems to me that the method that have to be implemented will contain the logic to retrieve my user information (so in my specific case where I have to put my web service call).

So in the same **app/Authentication** directory I have put this **UserProvider** implementing the **Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider** interface, this is my code:

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Authentication;

 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as IlluminateUserProvider;
 use GuzzleHttp\Client;
 use function GuzzleHttp\json_encode;
 use function GuzzleHttp\json_decode;

class UserProvider implements IlluminateUserProvider
{
public function retrieveById($identifier)
{
    // TODO: Implement retrieveById() method.
}

public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
{
    // TODO: Implement retrieveByToken() method.
}

public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
{
    // TODO: Implement updateRememberToken() method.
}

public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    // TODO: Implement retrieveByCredentials() method.

    $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client

    $response = $client->post('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
        [
            'auth' => [
                'Painkiller',
                'pswd'
            ]
        ]);


}

public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
{
    // TODO: Implement validateCredentials() method.
}

}
```

So I think that I have to put my webservice call in this method **retrieveByCredentials()**, this one:

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    // TODO: Implement retrieveByCredentials() method.

    $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client

    $response = $client->post('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
        [
            'auth' => [
                'Painkiller',
                'pswd'
            ]
        ]);


}
```

For semplicity, at this time I have hard coded the credential of an existing user returned by the web service doing performing an http request, so for any credential inserted by the user in the login form will always retrieve this user (I want to do a test...then I will integrate with the inserted credential).

Ok, this is the logic that I have understand following this tutorial, is it correct or am I missing something?

Then I start my Laravel project by the statment **php artisan serve** but I am obtaining the following error message:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/Betrivius/WorkSpace/betriviusExtranet (master)
$ php artisan serve
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider' not found in C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Betrivius\WorkSpace\betriviusExtranet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php on line 146


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider' not found
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have an AuthServiceProvider.php file in your app/Providers directory?

Comment: @Paras yes, have I to remove it?

Comment: I have already done something like this before, when I used Laravel 5.1. I just checked mine old Laravel 5.1 project, I saw that I had created 2 custom providers: `CustomAuthProvider` and `CustomUserProvider`. I would keep `AuthServiceProvider` as default

Comment: have run `composer dump-autoload -c` to reset up the application to take into account the new settings etc?

Comment: If you don't want to use the original     `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,` remove it form the providers array